# Echo Service Using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to Create a simple servlet to provide reversed-word echo service.

Example..
INPUT: JSTL was invented for creating prototype apps
OUTPUT: apps prototype creating for invented was JSTL

Using Eclipse